# Change Aegir Log Level?

Tags: aegir

The log messages for tasks seems pretty uninformative when you have an error. Is it possible to change the log level for task logs in Aegir? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to *Hosting » Settings » Task Logs to Display* and you can check/uncheck the boxes for the different types of log messages.

As [Add proper UX to the selector for choosing logs types to show](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting/issues/2960769) is fairly new (see that issue for background), it hasn't made it into a release yet so you'll probably still see the text area.